# Use Intel HD graphics for X server and left nvidia for GPU computation

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, gpu

I have a computer running an intel CPU (with hd graphics) and a nvidia geforce display card.

Since I just need the GPU for CUDA/OpenCL computation, I want to config the computer to use intel hd graphics instead to save video memory. Therefore, I try to switch back the primary display adapter from nvidia to intel hd graphics in BIOS.

However, if I switch to use intel hd graphics in my BIOS, /dev/nvidia0, /dev/nvidiactl and even some command like nvidia-smi will be disappear. When I run

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia               9430169  0
```

I can see nvidia module is loaded.

If I switch back the use nvidia in BIOS, /dev/nvidia0, /dev/nvidiactl and nvidia-smi command appear again.

How can I solve it?

I am running

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxxxx 3.8.0-32-generic #47~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 16:19:35 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS"
```

nvidia driver 319.37 from developer.nvidia.com ubuntu package directly ([here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads))